# How to only sum up values of a list in Prolog?

Tags: list, prolog, sum

I've been given this code below:

```
returnValues(Value):-
collection(X,Y,Z),
total([X,Y|Z],Value).
```

This does work, but it sums up X,Y and Z. I'm looking for it to sum up Z *only*.
Z is a list and I want to sum up the Values of Z.
Total is:

```
total([],0).   

total([Item|List],Sum):-
salary(Item,A), 
total(List,Rest),   
Sum is B + Rest.
```

I've tweaked the code a few times so that it only gives me values of X and Z, and only values of Y and Z, but I haven't been able to get values of Z only.

Sample input:

```
questionChildrenIncome(Name,Surname,CombinedIncome):-
family(Husband,person(Name,Surname,_,_),Children), 
total(Children,CombinedIncome),
CombinedIncome<100000,
member(Child,Children),
salary(Child,Salary),
Salary<30000.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just ignore X,Y like:

```
returnValues(Value):-
   collection(_,_,Z),
   total(Z,Value).
```

For your second comment you could write:

```
exclude([],[]).
exclude([H|T],[H|T1]):-salary(H,Salary),Salary<30000,exclude(T,T1).
exclude([H|T],T1):- salary(H,Salary),Salary>=30000,exclude(T,T1).
```

and change to :

```
questionChildrenIncome(Name,Surname,CombinedIncome):-
family(Husband,person(Name,Surname,_,_),Children), 
total(Children,CombinedIncome),
CombinedIncome<100000,
exclude(Children,Children)
```

.
You could also write more simply exclude predicate like:

```
exclude([]).
 exclude([H|T]):-salary(H,Salary),Salary<30000,exclude(T).
```

which succeeds only if all children have salary<30000.

Comment: I thought I had tried that one! Thanks, the code is working now.

Comment: Would you also know how I would be able to compare the individual elements of a list with a specific condition? I have a list where some of the members satisfy the condition and others don't, but I need to exclude all the members if any one of them does not meet the condition. Would you know how to code that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Would T and T1 not be two different lists? I only have one list. There are six values in this list and five of them meet this condition, but the sixth one fails, and so I have to exclude the five answers that are currently being returned because the sixth one failed. Hope this helps to clear it up. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you give a simple example of input list and output?

Comment: I've added a sample input above.

Comment: I have to get the income of children in a database. The conditions are that no individual child earns more than 30,000 and no group of children earn more than 100,000. The second condition is fine but when I query for individuals earning less than 30,000, I get two families back. One family has six children, five of whom are unemployed and the sixth earns 90,000. When I run the query I get five rows for that family, when I'd like to exclude them. The other family should be returned.

Comment: How do you query?? give a simple example of INPUT and OUTPUT you get and the DESIRED OUTPUT please...

Comment: The input for family would be something like
family(
 person(ned,jones,date(20,june,1949),unemployed),
 person(mary,jones,date(29,january,1948),unemployed),
 [ person(neil,jones,date(24,april,1983),works(food_bargains,90000)),
  person(mike,jones,date(23,may,1984),unemployed),
  person(ann,jones,date(23,may,1984),unemployed),
  person(eve,jones,date(23,may,1984),unemployed),
  person(louis,jones,date(2,november,1979),unemployed),
  person(charlie,jones,date(29,july,1989),unemployed)
 ]
).

Comment: The output currently is

Name = mary,
Surname = jones,
CombinedIncome = 90000 ;

and I get this five times.

The intended output is to exclude the family given here, and to only list the name and surname of the mother, and the children's combined income of those families that satisfy the given conditions.

Comment: Thanks so much!! It's giving me the right result! Would you mind explaining how you built that code and how you knew it'd work? Many thanks :) I don't have enough reputation on this website yet to mark it correct, but I will do that when I have.

Comment: It's nothing difficult with exclude you give as first list the Children list and you demand the output which is the second parameter to be Children list which means that there is no child with salary > 30000. If you see predicate exclude if a child has salary>30000 it doesn't adds it to the second list so in the end if second list equals to Children list this means that all children were added so all children had salary <30000.

Comment: Edited the answer by adding another way of writing exclude predicate so choose which you like most....

Comment: I deleted the third line of your second piece of code and I just got the same result back. Should that happen? Tried your latest code, but it gave errors.

Comment: Yes nice nice observation, this happens because it only uses the first two clauses. If it uses the last clause the this means that in your second list in the end some  children will be missing so it will fail. The same will happens if you delete third clause because if a child has salary>30000 it will correctly fail. This was exactly the idea in the last code , the reason that gave errors is because I didn't write it correctly. I edited the answer it should give correct result now the last code!